# Plotly Heatmap Subplot, Change Z Axis Range

Tags: python, heatmap, plotly, subplot

Is there any way to have a shared z axis when using a heatmap subplot? As you can see in the picture, the two plots have their own scale and the numbers 60, 40 and 20 appear twice.

[image: Calendar Heatmap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to set zmin=1, zmax=100 in both heatmaps.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update in terms of newer versions: in v4 you can specify a shared coloraxis, and update properties for the specified coloraxis in layout: e.g. for python

```
fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z = z, x = x, y = y, coloraxis = 'coloraxis1'))
fig.update_layout(coloraxis1 = {'colorscale':'Electric'})
```